# how the jquery will be helpful to open a popup window?

Tags: jquery

code for jquery popup window and rich text editor...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>LIGHTBOX EXAMPLE</title>
<SCRIPT>
function clearDefaultandCSS(el) {
if (el.defaultValue==el.value) el.value = ""
// If Dynamic Style is supported, clear the style
if (el.style) el.style.cssText = ""
}
</SCRIPT>
<style>
.black_overlay{
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 0%;
left: 0%;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color:#9A9A9C;
z-index:1001;
-moz-opacity: 0.8;  
opacity:.80;
filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}
.white_content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 25%;
left: 25%;
width: 30%;
height: 40%;
background-color: #FFF;
z-index:1200;
overflow: auto;
border-radius: 10px;
ms-border-radius: 10px;
right: 25%;
bottom: 25%;
padding: 25px;
}
.button {
display: inline-block;
min-width: 54px;
text-align: center;
color: #555;
font-size: 11px;
font-weight: bold;
height: 27px;
padding: 0 8px;
line-height: 27px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.218s;
-moz-transition: all 0.218s;
-ms-transition: all 0.218s;
-o-transition: all 0.218s;
transition: all 0.218s;
border: 1px solid gainsboro;
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
background-color: whiteSmoke;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left              bottom,from(#f5f5f5),to(#f1f1f1));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#f5f5f5,#f1f1f1);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#f5f5f5,#f1f1f1);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top,#f5f5f5,#f1f1f1);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#f5f5f5,#f1f1f1);
background-image: linear-gradient(top,#f5f5f5,#f1f1f1);
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
cursor: default;

}
</style>
</head>
<body style="overflow:hidden">
<a href = javascript:void(0) onclick =   "document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">Login</a>
<div id="light" class="white_content" style="overflow:hidden"> 
<div align="justify">
<img  align="right" src='file:///C|/Users/vptr/Desktop/close.png'  onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">
</div>
<p align="left" style="color:#006633; font: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: xx-large">Log In to <span style="color:#000">Grill</span></p>

<table>
<form action="" method="get">
<tr> <td colspan="2"><input TYPE="text" 
 placeholder="Email/Username"
 style="height:30px; width:200px; color:#0CF" 
 ONFOCUS="clearDefaultandCSS(this)"></td> </tr><br>
<tr> <td colspan="2"><input type="password"  
 placeholder="password"
 style="height:30px; width:200px; color:#063"s
 TITLE="password"
 ONFOCUS="clearDefaultandCSS(this)"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit" class="button" value="Login"></td><td><p><a href="#"><span style="color:#033">Forgot password</a></p></td></tr>
</span></form>
</table>
<div align="center" ><p>Create an <a href= ><span style="color:#033">Account</span></a>                <p></div>
</div>
<div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code is useful to create a log in popup window using jquery.

here i used java script to open a popup window, i want to know how the popup window is opening.

and using this same script how to open another popup when i click on forget password.

Answer (score 0):

It comes from the onclick value. But this is really bad code. You have javascript inside your html, which for various is not good. you should keep style, code and content separated when possible.

```
<a href = javascript:void(0) onclick =   "document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">Login</a>
```

Basically this right here, it will find the div 
 
because it has an id of light. It will then set the display to block, since by default it is hidden. It will also show a background overlay to black it out. This is all done using css. Notice how the div with id light has the class white_content. This is how it's styled.

honestly, if you have jquery and want to use it, then why not use it. This is just straight up css and javascript, no jquery here. You can download many plugins for this type of thing too.

Take a look at http://fancybox.net/, this will allow you to easily separate the code from the html.

If you wanted to keep this code to create another one simply do something like:

```
<a href = javascript:void(0) onclick =   "document.getElementById('newpopup').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">New Popup</a>
```

`<div id="newpopup" class="white_content" style="overflow:hidden">`

`Anything you want in here`

`</div>`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this markup has no jQuery in it.

*Show "light" & "fade" elements on click of "Login" button:*

```
<a href=javascript:void(0)
   onclick="document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';
            document.getElementById('fade') .style.display='block'">Login</a>`
```

*Hide "light" and "fade" elements on click of close image:*

```
<img align="right"
     src='file:///C|/Users/vptr/Desktop/close.png'
     onclick="document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';
              document.getElementById('fade') .style.display='none'">
```